# Show users which button he has clicked

Tags: java, css, button, javafx

I have 3 buttons to show different panels.
If I press the button `btn_All` the `pnl_All` should also appear, etc.
Well, I want to let the user know where he is.
If he presses the `btn_All` also the panel `pnl_All` should appear additionally the button should get a certain class of CSS added.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do that?

You could add the CSS class to the button by code, but then I would have to remove them from the buttons, so I find this option very cumbersome.

Main.java

```
package sample;

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_GraphicCard,pnl_Processors,pnl_All;

    @FXML
    private Button btn_GraphicCard,btn_Processors,btn_All;

    @FXML
    void buttonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == btn_All) {
            pnl_All.toFront();
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == btn_GraphicCard) {
            pnl_GraphicCard.toFront();
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == btn_Processors){
            pnl_Processors.toFront();
        }

    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="pnl_GraphicCard" layoutX="317.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="284.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" />
      <Pane fx:id="pnl_Processors" layoutX="317.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="284.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" />
      <Pane fx:id="pnl_All" layoutX="317.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="284.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" />
      <Button fx:id="btn_GraphicCard" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="59.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" text="Processors" />
      <Button fx:id="btn_Processors" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="96.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" text="GraphicCard" />
      <Button fx:id="btn_All" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="27.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" text="All" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

style.css

```
.button:active{
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: This would most likely be easier to do using a group of [`ToggleButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html)s and a [`ToggleGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html). Then you can use the `ToggleButton`'s `selected` pseudo-class in your CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you need is exectly what `ToggleButton` and `ToggleGroup` are for:

Ti implement it, change your `Buttons` to `ToggleButtons`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="src.tests.xml.Controller">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="pnl_GraphicCard" layoutX="317.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="284.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" />
      <Pane fx:id="pnl_Processors" layoutX="317.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="284.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" />
      <Pane fx:id="pnl_All" layoutX="317.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="284.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="btn_GraphicCard" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="59.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" text="Processors" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="btn_Processors" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="96.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" text="GraphicCard" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="btn_All" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="27.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" text="All" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And create a group, so only one can be selected :

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_GraphicCard,pnl_Processors,pnl_All;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton btn_GraphicCard,btn_Processors,btn_All;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        ToggleGroup bg = new ToggleGroup();
        bg.getToggles().addAll( btn_GraphicCard,btn_Processors,btn_All);
    }

    @FXML
    void buttonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == btn_All) {
            pnl_All.toFront();
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == btn_GraphicCard) {
            pnl_GraphicCard.toFront();
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == btn_Processors){
            pnl_Processors.toFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "So several buttons are displayed as pressed in" - if you applied the posted code, only **one** button is selected at any given time. If that is not the case, you may have a problem in the initialization of the toggle group  (left out `implements Initializable` ? )

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. Forgot an `extends` Thank you very much!

Comment: @c0der is the best :D

Comment: We lost contact here. But whenever I look at your answers on whatever issues I had, I can see how helpfull you were for me and my application.